# How to test jPlayer (or any Flash / HTML5 audio) in a headless state?

Tags: integration-testing, bdd, phantomjs, jplayer, headless-browser

I have created functionality that relies heavily on jPlayer interactions (http://jplayer.org/). My local integration tests work fine (using Capybara) but I am having trouble testing on my development server (Linux / Ubuntu 12.04). I have tried Selenium, capybara-webkit, and PhantomJS - but none of them support Flash or HTML5 audio. I have stuck with PhantomJS as I find it most enjoyable with which to test.

How can I perform headless integration tests that interact with jPlayer (either in HTML5 audio or Flash mode)?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/), which is a headless browser based on `Gecko`.

Based on this issue: https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/13, it seems slimerjs supports requests sent from flash.

Thanks.

Comment: Direct from the SlimerJS documentation:  "Contrary to PhantomJS, SlimerJS is not headless: you see windows and it needs a graphical environment."